# How to perform one to one mapping in scala?

Tags: scala

```
var a= List(1,2,3,4,5)

var b=List(4,5)
```

I want answer of List((1,4),(2,5),(3,4),(4,5),(5,4))

I am using map right now but it is not giving me perfect answer.

How can I get this?

Comment: Your question is not well defined. You want to zip the lists where 'b' is cyclic?

Comment: So you want list of tupples?

Comment: Yes Felix I want the same

Comment: So you want to take each element of the first list in turn, match it with the next element of the second list, and when you run out of elements of the second list, repeat from the beginning of the second list? The answer you accepted doesn;'t do that.

Comment: Please show an example that doesn't have any of the same values in list and b

Comment: Sebastien's solution is runnign for me ... Actually i want to to copy the values of b while zipping until the a values lasts

Comment: Right, that's what I said (I think). And yes, Sebastian's suggestion is neat.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much simpler:

```
val a = List(1,2,3,4,5)
val b = List(4,5)
a zip Stream.continually(b).flatten
```

Result: `List((1,4), (2,5), (3,4), (4,5), (5,4))`

Comment: Thanks..Its perfectly running . :)

Comment: Nice.  I failed to find Stream.continually :(

Answer (score 3):

Your inout is somewhat lacking, but for the sake of the puzzle the answer for the exact parameters of your question would be

```
val a = List(1,2,3)
val b = List(4,5)

val temp1 = a ::: b
// make sure temp 2 is at least as long as temp1
val temp2 = List.fill((temp1.size / b.size) + 1)(b).flatten

val result = temp1 zip temp2
```

However, I guess there would be better ones, if you could give more details.

**EDIT**

In response to an edit in the question:

```
val a = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
val b = List(4,5)

val result = a zip List.fill((a.size / b.size) + 1)(b).flatten
```

Comment: No it's not. On `val a = List(1,2,3, 4, 5); val b =List(6,7)` it  gives  `List((1,6), (2,7), (3,6), (4,7), (5,6), (6,7), (7,6))`

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Hmm, please help me, I do not see what would be wrong with that result. Though, I fixed an issue your answer made me aware of.

Comment: However, I think Sebastians answer still wins ;)

Comment: I don't see that elements from b should appear first in any tuples.

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Ok, the question has been edited, when I answered, **a** in the question was just `List(1, 2, 3)`. I hate it when that happens :(

Answer (score 1):

I think you want this:

```
 a zip List.fill(a.length / b.length + 1)(b).flatten
```

but it's difficult to tell. Using a different example (without overlapping values)

```
val a = List(1,2,3, 4, 5)
val b = List(6,7)

a zip List.fill(a.length / b.length + 1)(b).flatten
//> res1: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,6), (2,7), (3,6), (4,7), (5,6))
```